# Celery Task not retrying as Expected

Tags: python, celery

I am working on a celery project. I had some old code that I am trying to re-use on a new environment. It's rather simple. 
My failure condition is when another task returns the blank string. The two tasks are below.

```
@app.task(track_started=True, bind=True)
def get_latakoo_transcript(self, latakoo_object_id):
    return my_client.get_transcript(latakoo_object_id).json()['result']['transcription']



@app.task(track_started=True, bind=True)
def add_latakoo_transcript(self, latakoo_document):
    latakoo_object_id = latakoo_document.get_document()['headers']['id']
    transcript = get_latakoo_transcript(latakoo_object_id)

    if transcript == '':
        print('-----------------------')
        print(latakoo_object_id)
        self.retry(countdown=1,  max_retries=100)
    else:
        success = latakoo_document.add_transcript(transcript)
        response = latakoo_document.insert_document(extra_collections=['untagged'])
    return latakoo_document
```

Anytime the retry mechanism hits. It prints, but does not do the retry.

> Task
>   nbcu_nes_ingest.Tasks.ClassificationTasks.insert_latakoo_object[94e5388d-f1a6-4649-a75a-207a5dcd3388]
>   retry: Task can be retried.

I have the same logic, on an older version `if str == '': retry` of the project which works just fine.

My local development machine is Windows 7. Using Python 3.3. Celery Version 3.1.8.

If anyone has any thoughts please let me know. 
I've tried doing things with try catch block, and raiseing the retry, but nothing seems to work.

edit: Adding Celery App constructor

```
app = Celery('ClassificationTasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', backend='amqp',)
```